# Subir dados pro Azure

Tags: microsoft-azure, sistema-de-arquivos, sharepoint, ssis

Alguém sabe se há a possibilidade de subir os dados de um arquivo pra um DataLake no Azure?

Por exemplo, um serviço do DataTools seria executado e ele acessaria um repositório dentro de uma máquina do usuário, e depois subiria somente os dados (não os arquivos), pro DataLake no Azure.

Se falei alguma bobagem, me corrijam. To iniciando agora nesse mundo da Engenharia de Dados e ainda estou bem perdida.

Se há alguma outra forma de fazer isso, seja pelo SharePoint ou outro modo, podem falar também. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível fazer o upload dos arquivos para um data lake utilizando o [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/data-factory/), basta criar um pipeline que acessa o filesystem da origem dos arquivos e copiá-los para o destino.

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-copy-data-tool) tem um tutorial semelhante que pode te auxiliar no processo, basta mudar o conector de origem para filesystem ao invés de blob storage.